# USB multiplexer with common bus

Tags: usb, usb-c, usb-hub

Okay this is indeed a dumb question but I would like to know if this is feasible. I want to create a usb mux that can connect a common USB port to 4 ports. There is an IC TS3USB221 that does the same thing but b/w 2 USB ports. Is it possible to keep the D-/D+ and ground common among 4 USB ports and have a switch 1:4 that connects the common port VBUS to target port VBUS. Rough diagram shown below...

[image]

Comment: Hubs were designed for a reason. Your solution might work but it is highly dependent on what the devices are.

Comment: I've seen USB Hubs with individual power switches for each device. That would be the proper solution here.

Comment: What is _”b/w”_? Black and white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In case it is multiple hosts, single device...**

The proposal does not work. As all data lines are connected, all hosts will detect when a device is connected. They will all start driving the data lines to communicate with the device, causing conflicts both at the electrical level and at the protocol level.

A possible solution is to use two 1:2 multiplexer chips in parallel, each one serving two USB hosts. On the device side, both chips are connected to the device's data lines in parallel. With the output enable (OE) signal it can be ensured that only one of the multiplexer's is active at any time.

This does not yet address where the multiplexer gets its power from, and how the multiplexer is controlled. I don't see the need to switch VBUS in the first place. The multiplexer likely needs an independent power supply. It could feed the multiplexer and the device at the same time.

**In case it is single host, multiple devices...**

There are several problems with the proposed approach:

- If multiple data lines are connected in a star topology, signal reflections will distort the data signals. This is mainly a problem for high-speed signals.
- Even if a device has no power, it might still have active pull-up resistors on the data lines.
- It certainly does not work for self-powered devices as they stay active even if the host or MUX doesn't provide any power to them.

You might get away with the approach if:

- You are only using full-speed (12Mbit/s) and not high-speed (480MBit/s).
- All devices are connected with short cables to minimize reflections.
- All devices are bus-powered.
- All devices' D+ and D' lines are high impedance when they are not powered.

A possible solution is to use two 1:2 multiplexer chips in parallel, each one serving two USB devices. On the host side, both chips are connected to the host's D+/D- in parallel. With the output enable (OE) signal it can be ensured that only one of the multiplexer's is active at any time.

For VBUS, separate switches (MOSFETs) are needed anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the very detail reply.

Comment: I came across the below HUB IC.

https://oshwlab.com/karrr/fe1-1s-usb-hub-submodule

Seems like the power is given from external power supply. to IC and to Ports. Shouldn't the VBUS comes from Host PC or external is also possible. Also in that schematics, if I connect one port with Host and connect/disconnect power from one of the remaining 4 devices, will it work?

Comment: It gets trickier with a hub. It certainly does not work for self-powered devices. It does not work if the host is a microcontroller without support for hubs in its firmware. And it might be problematic if a device without power doesn't go high impedance. You would have to test how the chip behaves under that condition. What's the use case anyway? If you can provide more context, it would help.

Comment: Once again thank for the comment. Unfortunately I don't exactly know the target devices nature. All I know is non of them will be self powered. :(

Comment: But what's the use case? Why does it have to be a multiplexer instead of a hub? Why don't you connect a 5$ USB hub to your PC, connect the four devices and call it a day?

Comment: Okay the use case is like: We have a debugger say: JLink. We have some testing on windows and linux. At a time we want to connect it to one host. so one usb connected to JLINK and two host. The connection is dynamically switched. Hub is not feasible in this case. any other suggested solution, please?

Comment: So it's multiple host computers and a single USB device? That changes everything.

Comment: USB switch boxes to connect a device to two or more hosts exist. Unknown if they fit your purpose.

Comment: Yes, USB switches exist (both as consumer-ready boxes and PCB designer-friendly ICs), and they make and break connections on the D+ and D- lines.  Switching VBUS is not sufficient.

Comment: Any Specific IC that you can recommend?

Comment: Can you confirm that you will have multiple hosts and a single USB device, and not the other way round?

Comment: Nope. Both ways are possible. I think its too theoretical. Isn't it?

Comment: I have decided to use 1:2 USB mux IC.

Comment: I am marking your reply as answer. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Likely this won't work at all, for many reasons. It will not be feasible to even try this, as it is wrong in so many levels. If it were possible and allowed by USB specs, this idea would already be used everywhere, but it isn't.

The bus would be split into four and that star point itself is a problematic topology for many buses, not just USB.

Devices will also very likely have protection diodes from USB data pins to supply, so any unpowered device would just load down data bus and prevent the whole bus from working.